# High Number of Views in the TERADATA DataBase

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a question. In an application close to 500 views have been designed based on different reportable granularities. My concern is will this high number impact performance of the application in any way. One more point , the views are interlinked. So all of the views are accessed at some point of time. Could you please provide insights on this.

Thanks And Regards
Aritra Bhattacharya

Comment: 500 views is not that much and there's no difference between using views or directly writing SELECTs with various conditions (the parser resolves the source code of the views). But if *interlinked* means nested views more than 2 levels developed easily loose track and this might result in overly complex queries...

Comment: Yes they are interlinked to more than two levels and the 500 views are only specific to our application, many other applications are also use that particular database and so i was thinking that having so many interlinked views would mess up the performance. @dnoeth

Comment: Are those views complex, i.e. involving joins/aggregation/etc.?

Comment: yes. Both joins and Aggregations. @dnoeth

Comment: It's hard to tell if those nested views could be unnested and simplified. If the performance gets worse you might have to investigate.